# Strange behaviour of SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a query in a validation stored procedure. It goes something like this:

```
SELECT *  
FROM Table1  
WHERE batchID IN (SELECT id FROM #tempIds) 
  AND CAST(field1 AS DATE) > CAST(field2 AS DATE)
```

Both `field1` and `field2` have valid dates, i.e. doing IdDate on field1/2 returns 1.

The `#tempIds` table only has one column `ID` and contains only one row.

When I run the above query, I get this error:

> Unable to convert varchar to date

But instead of selecting batch ids from temp table if I put hard-coded ID from the same temp table it works.

Any ideas what could be the issue?

Comment: "Unable to convert varchar to date" means either `field1` or `field2` has a varchar value that can't be converted to date. The error text is quite self explanatory.

Comment: If #tempIds is going to have only one row then assign id value to local variable and use that local variable in where clause with "=" and not IN

Comment: Something like?   What you describe does not make sense.

Comment: To expand on @ZoharPeled statement, most likely you are finding this because your hard coded ID doesn't return the same (invalid) dates as the select. Using one ID most likely has far less results than using all the IDs in the temp table.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I have already checked that both the fields have correct date for given ID.

Comment: the other thing I would like you to focus on is that the temp table only has one ID, if instead doing IN (SELECT id FROM #tempids) if I take the values of id from #tempids and put the hardcoded value inside the IN statement like this IN (1023), then it works perfectly fine.

Comment: *"for the given if"* - but the where clause is searching other records as well. You are storing dates as varchar - untill that's fixed you will always have problems with dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `varchar` to store `date` (or `datetime`) values.
Choosing the correct data type for your columns would save you from a lot of problems, this one included. For detailed information, read Aaron Bertrand's [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type).

Now, to address our conversation in the comments - **SQL Server does not guarantee the order on which the conditions in the where clause are evaluated.** This means that even if all the "date" strings in both your columns are convertible to date values for the specific `batchID`, you only need one wrong value in one of the columns to raise the "Unable to convert `varchar` to date" error.

This also means that even if you where to write your query the way Larry B suggested in his answer (now deleted - so for the sake of future readers - this was his suggestion:)

```
SELECT *  
FROM Table1  
WHERE batchID IN (SELECT id FROM #tempIds) 
AND ISDATE(field1) = 1 
AND ISDATE(field2) = 1 
AND CAST(field1 AS DATE) > CAST(field2 AS DATE)
```

There is no guarantee that the last condition (`cast(field1 as date) > cast(field2 as date)`) will be evaluated **after** the `isdate(field1)=1` condition.

**The correct thing to do is to fix the problem** - change the data types of the columns to the correct data type.

Assuming that can't be done (if you have no control over the structure of the database, for instance) - you can do a couple of things:

1. Find all the places where the values in `field1` and in `field2` can't be converted to dates and fix them. Consider adding a check constraint to validate that the values of these columns can be converted to date (assuming you can).
2. Separate your query into 2 parts:

```sql
;With cte as
(
    SELECT *  
    FROM Table1  
    WHERE batchID IN (SELECT id FROM #tempIds) 
    AND ISDATE(field1) = 1 
    AND ISDATE(field2) = 1 
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE CAST(field1 AS DATE) > CAST(field2 AS DATE)
```

This will eliminate the error, since you are only casting values where the `ISDATE` function already returned 1, but might not return some rows you want back, if the value if either `field1` or `field2` is wrong in these rows.

Comment: Thanks Zohar, actually the Table1 is a data warehouse table and data from a file is loaded into this table and before moving that data to the actual business table I need to validate the data... and that is where I was getting that error... This solution works... Thanks for your answer...

Comment: @ZoharPeled My solution is incorrect therefore I deleted it; but my point was that I wanted to be helpful even when the question seemed bad. Had he asked the question and included isdate in the where clause like I did then you would have easily spotted it. Now that he's made some clarification the question points to a fact that I never realized and that's the order of evaluation in the where clause. How have I used so many variations of SQL for so long and never realized that blows my mind! Seems you got a two for one!

Comment: @LarryB First, I'm glad I could also help another person. Second, I've edited my answer to show your suggested sql since you deleted yours.

Comment: Hi guys, if you think my question was worth asking on StackOverflow, can you please upvote it? Stack overflow is not letting me post other question.

Comment: "Stackoverflow is not letting me post other question" - Because of this one? I've never heard about people being blocked for low quality questions here. Sorry, but your question, while not that bad to score -6, is also not good enough for an upvote.